# Fluentbit Tag Modifications

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am using fluent-bit to send all of my K8S logs to Elasticsearch. Currently, I want to ship all of the logs for which I have included the string syslog. Then, if a log includes the following string: ""syslog": true," I want it to also be shipped to a different "syslog" output plugin.

How can I do this?

Thank you